# EFK stack - fluentd not sending logs to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, efk

I am working on a EFK stack for log management in microservices.

Problem statement: Unable to send logs to ElasticSearch from Fluentd, though it was was working earlier with the same setup. Transmission to ElasticSearch has stopped all of sudden.

Checks:

1. Fluentd logs:
   [image]
2. ElasticSearch is running

[image]

3. ElasticSearch logs:
   [image]

Note: It was working perfectly till 18 June 2022 and I can see the logs in kibana but suddenly stop working since 20th June 2022.

yaml file for the deployment is pressent at:
https://github.com/Jindu0506/efk-stack

Need you help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Can you change fluentd log to 'debug'? This way you will have more info on why the logs are not sent.

Comment: ok. I have tried and worked fine. Actually I was missing the indexing in elasticsearch. It is resolved now. Thanks